# Test if executable exists in unix

Tags: shell, unix, zsh

### Problem

I may or may not have the executable `thing` in my `$PATH`.

How can I neatly check this in a ZSH script?

### Existing Attempt

I just run the command, sending the output and errors or noman's land, then check the result code.

```
thing > /dev/null 2>&1
thing_installed=$?
if [ $thing_installed -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'Thing Installed!'
fi
```

I feel like this could be done more neatly (one liner?).

Comment: from the man page on test ... `-x file  True if file exists and is executable.  True indicates only
                   that the execute flag is on.  If file is a directory, true
                   indicates that file can be searched.`

Comment: Amusing that you accepted an answer that has a score of `-4`!

Comment: @devnull I accepted the answer which worked for me. It didn't have a `-4` when I accepted it... Glad you got some amusement out of it though ;)

Comment: @PeterHamilton It's not a matter of being amused or not.  It's sad to see unhelpful or wrong answers being accepted as those do not help any future visitors.

Comment: Which is why I changed it. Why do I feel like you're accusing me of something? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In zsh, `which` behaves reasonably, so you can simply do

```
if which thing > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo installed
fi
```

or

```
which thing > dev/null 2>&1 && echo installed
```

Note that which is a shell builtin, and its behavior is *not* reasonable in all shells, so this behavior cannot be relied upon.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this first, but the [ -e thing ] method with longform if was nicer IMO.

Comment: This more accurately answers your question, which specifically asked if `thing` was in your path.

Comment: "nicer" is an interesting definition for a solution that completely fails to work!  Try `test -e ls` to answer the question 'is `ls` installed on my machine?'

Comment: @WilliamPursell That is the beauty of SO.  You can have _accepted answers_ that are completely wrong.

Comment: (It's nice to see an _accepted answer_ with a score of `-4` and counting!)

Comment: @WilliamPursell it worked in my case obviously by luck but I see now it was wrong, obviously now you guys have pointed out the flaws I've changed my accepted solution. *That's* the beauty of SO.

Answer (score 1):

For zsh `whence` is the tool you are looking for. With parameter `-p` it can be forced to look only in `$PATH` and ignore functions, builtins and aliases with the same name.

This will either return the path to `thing` or an error message:

```
whence -cp thing
```

Answer (score 0):

use `which thing` and check result code

Answer (score -4):

You can check whether the file exists by this expresion:

```
[ -e thing ] && echo 'Thing Installed!'
```

The `-e` operator checks whether the file exists or not. If you want to do other file tests take a look to this page: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html.

Hope this was helpful ;-)

Comment: I didn't think this would work with executables, awesome, cheers.

Comment: `[ -e thing]` does neither check executabilty nor does it look in `$PATH`. For this to find anyhing `thing` has to be in the current directory and even then it may be a directory instead of an executable file.